# Cannot convert ‘libraryname::ZlibCompressor’ to ‘libraryname::Compressor*’ in assignment (to an array index)

Tags: c++, leveldb

```
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:10:26: error: cannot convert ‘libraryname::ZlibCompressor’ to ‘libraryname::Compressor*’ in assignment
   options.compressors[0] = libraryname::ZlibCompressor();
```

`options` is a struct, and `compressors` is defined as:

```
Compressor* compressors[256];
```

ZlibCompressor is a subclass of Compressor.

Any idea why this error is occurring? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options.compressors[0] = libraryname::ZlibCompressor();
```

The type of `options.compressors[0]` is `Compressor *`, which is *pointer*. you should give a pointer.

```
libraryname::ZlibCompressor zc;
options.compressors[0] = &zc;
```